# How make in ember array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm new in EmberJs.

I've this function,

```
producerTypes: ( ->
  types = @get('model.registrations').mapBy('type').compact().uniq()
  //Here array of hashes to types and another model call requirements
).property('model.registrations')
```

how make a array of hashes in ember?

Thanks'  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  producerRequirements: ( ->
    documentation = []
    types = @get('model.registrationsDocumentations').
              mapBy('producerType').compact().uniq()  //first map by type
    for producerType in types
      requirements = @get('model.registrationsDocumentations').
                          filterBy('producerType', producerType)   //second filter by producerType
      documentation.addObject(               //add to the array
        producerType: producerType,
        requirements: requirements
      )
    documentation
  ).property('model.registrationsDocumentations.@each')
```